# waiting for completion of get request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have to get several pages of a json API with about 130'000 entries.

The request is fairly simple with:

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
```

Where the querystring is an access token and the headers fairly simple.

I created a while loop where basically every request url is in the form of

```
https://urlprovider.com/endpointname?pageSize=10000&rowStart=0
```

and the rowStart increments by pageSize until there is no more further pages.

The problem I encounter is the following response after about 5-8 successful requests:

```
{'errorCode': 'ERROR_XXX', 'code': 503, 'message': 'Maximum limit for unprocessed API requests have been reached. Please try again later.', 'success': False}
```

From the error message I get that I initiate the next request before the last has finished. Does anyone know how I can make sure the get request has finished before the next one starts (except something crude like a `sleep()`) or if the error could lie elsewhere?

Comment: You can't have done that with this code. Either you're using some kind of asynchronous approach that you haven't shown, or the API is giving a spurious error maybe related to exceeding a request limit

Comment: requests is synchronous, so it will wait until the request has completed before moving on to the next line of code. Could the website be restricting the number of calls from an ip address in a given time frame to prevent bots scraping them?

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh and Dan. The synchronous nature of requests explains why I have found no answer to my question, I understand my requirement is already the case. It is very possible that the error message from the apiprovider is wrong then and that I'll have to find another approach and/or ask them to increase the limit.

Comment: A long shot, but you might want to create a [Session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects). It's hard to know what the issue is here.

Comment: @roganjosh perfect! Your long shot with Sessions worked! I will write it up as an answer and accept it. Thanks a lot. It also improves performance. Especially as I found out in the meantime that a sleep() of minimum 10 seconds would have worked as well but would have been very crude

Comment: I'm glad that you've found your solution. But personally I think it would be polite to give @roganjosh the opportunity to write his comment as an answer, so he could take the credit (i.e. reputation) for it. Reputation is the way to say "Thank you" on Stack Overflow ;-) You might consider that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out wovano. @roganjosh I can delete my answer if you want to write your own. It is absolutely true that I just summarized what you pointed me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

1. Requests is synchronous, meaning that it will ALWAYS wait until the the call has finished before continuing
2. The response from the API provider is misleading, as the request has thus already been processed before the next one comes.
3. The root cause is difficult to assess, but it may be to do with a limit imposed by the API provider

What has worked:

- A crude `sleep(10)`, which makes the program wait 10 seconds before processing the next request
- Better solution: Create a [Session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects). According to the documentation:

> The Session object [...] will use urllib3’s connection pooling. So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).

Not only does this resolve the problem but also increases the performance compared to my initial code.